# Access to Bluemix results in a "Failed to find resource" error

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I try to log into Bluemix, I see `JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource` error message. What is the cause of this issue?

Here is the complete message:

```
JSP Processing Error
HTTP Error Code:   500

Error Message:

/jsp/authn_failediif.jsp(77,50) JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /jsp/include/generalmsg.shtml

Root Cause:

com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: /jsp/authn_failediif.jsp(77,50) JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /jsp/include/generalmsg.shtml
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocumentAsJspPage(Jsp2Dom.java:518)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocument(Jsp2Dom.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslator.<init>(JspTranslator.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslatorFactory.createTranslator(JspTranslatorFactory.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJsp(JspTranslatorUtil.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJspAndCompile(JspTranslatorUtil.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:565)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:487)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:156)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are not asking a question. Do you need to fix the server error? Or you are a user experiencing that as a client, and need to know what to do? People here will need more context in order to help you

Comment: I am a user trying to get access to Bluemix. When I Put my user-id and password I got that error

Comment: Are you still seeing the same error today?

Answer (score 0):

the first thing to do with this kind of problems is to check that your local cache isn't taking you this error: so you may empty your browser cache and cookies and try again.
If you will get the same error, you may check on

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

on the right column, for any running maintenance activity or for a platform issue alert.
If everything is ok you should request Bluemix team for support following the instructions you find on
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/getting_customer_support.html
Section "Contacting Bluemix support"